# difference between call missing of an array and setting every element of array to zero

Tags: arrays, sas

Consider

```
data want;
set have;
array ay1{7};
retain ay1:;

if first.tcol then do;
call missing(of ay1{*});
end;

if ay1{7} > a then do;
[other statements to determine value of ay1]
end;

else do;
[other statements to determine value of ay1]
end;

by tcol;
run;
```

Since array `ay1` will be automatically retained between observations, if I want the program to do some by-group processing, I need to reset `ay1` values when it encounter a new `tcol` value (otherwise it will inherit values from last observation of previous `tcol` value. This will affect `if ay{7} > a`, hence all other statements followed will by affected).

In my current codes, I will reset the array by

```
do i = 1 to dim(ay1);
ay1{i} = 0;
end;
```

And this work fines. For the first obs of each `tcol` value, It will first reset all values of `ay1` to 0 and then perform `[other statement]` to update `ay1` in this observation.

If I use `call missing(of ay1{*});`, for the first obs of each `tcol` value, it will set each value of `ay1` to missing (as expected). But the following `[other statement]` will **NOT** update `ay1`. (I have placed several put statements in `[other statement]` as debug step to make sure this part has run. It does all other work except updating `ay1` value).

If `first.tcol` fails, everything seems back to normal (no error but the output data set is wrong since first step in each by group has all unexpected values). So I think there must be something wrong about using `call missing` here.

Comment: Suggest you modify your code to show an actual HAVE dataset (5 records) and also show the [other statement] that you see as NOT updating ay1.  If people have sample data and sample code, it will help them debug.  I can't see how using CALL MISSING would cause a problem like you're describing.

Comment: You should put your BY statement right after the SET statement.  What if your data step had other SET or MERGE statements?  Your BY might be applied to the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement "Since array ay1 will be automatically retained between observations" is incorrect.  Arrays declared as `_TEMPORARY_` are retained automatically.  Arrays of permanent variables are not.

You can test this with:

```
data want;
set have;
array ay1{7};
by tcol;

if first.tcol then do;
    do i=1 to 7;
        ay1[i] = 1;
    end;
end;
run;
```

You will see that after the first tcol value in each group, the values will be missing.  I.E. they were not retained between rows.

Add

```
retain ay:;
```

to your Data Step and it should work as you expect.

EDIT: Added this to show it works as described.

```
data have;
tcol = 1;
a = 1;
output;
tcol = 1;
a = 10;
output;
run;

data want;
set have;
array ay1{7};
retain ay1:;
by tcol;

if first.tcol then do;
    call missing(of ay1{*});
end;

if ay1{7} > a then do;
    do i=1 to 7;
        ay1[i] = -a;
    end;
end;

else do;
    do i=1 to 7;
        ay1[i] = 999;
    end;
end;

run;
```

Comment: I'd quibble about the difference between a newly created variable and a set/merge/update-sourced variable, but I suspect that's not worth complicating things :)

Comment: `Arrays of permanent variables are not retained.` - unless you set initial values for the array variables in the array statement.